# Where is the latest AWS Amplify API documentation for Android

Tags: android, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I've searched everywhere, but I could not find the AWS Amplify API documentation for Android

The Amplify framework for Android have nice examples, for example [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android#initialize-amplify-auth)

You can see in the above link, this example code:

```
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSCognitoAuthPlugin());
Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext());
```

But i want to see what other parameters can `addPlugin` or `configure` method have and to read their
description, and I cannot find the documentation anywhere !!!

and please don't tell me its the API Reference Tab they have on top
because i went in that and saw a huge documentation that has not mentioned `configure()` not `addPlugin()` APIs

[image]

Anyone ? any clues ?

Comment: Everything is there in [Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/android). Please check it properly they have given step by step. If you have any query please let me know. Yesterday i have implemented and it is working properly .

Comment: The link you posted is only there step by step walkthrough (tutorial). Again - where is the API definition for methods like configure(), what arguments it receives? what it returns? what are the arguments that each and every android amplify method ???? can you please send me a link to that ?

Comment: You have to configure using command in terminal. please have a look at [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/android)

Comment: I wasn't asking how to configure... But this configure i am talking about is a method in the android amplify lib called like this: Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext());.   did you know that you can call it also like this Amplify.configure(configuration, context);  ???   i saw that in the code - I want to see API documentation of this function ? Where is it ????????????

Comment: @Mercury have you been able to find this documentation? I'm having the same issue - can't find a single resource with documentation on the functions for AWS Amplify, i can only find their tutorials and step-by-step configurations... If you have anything, would be super helpful